# Why does Nokogiri::CSS.xpath_for return an array?

Tags: ruby, xpath, css-selectors, nokogiri

I'm looking at the source code of Nokogiri::CSS, because I needed to convert CSS selectors to XPATH. After running a sample code and calling the xpath_for method, I see that it returns an array. Why is this? Are there any chances a CSS selector would return more than one xpath?

```
[18] pry(main)> Nokogiri::CSS.xpath_for 'div.divddy input:first'
=> ["//div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' divddy ')]//input[position() = 1]"]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [CSS selector can contain multiple components separated by commas](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#grouping):

> **5. Groups of selectors**
>
> A comma-separated list of selectors represents the union of all elements selected by each of the individual selectors in the list.

For example:

```
div.divddy input:first, div#where_is input.pancakes_house { /*...*/ }
```

So presumably [`xpath_for`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/CSS.html#method-c-xpath_for) returns an array in case you hand it a grouped selector. For example:

```
>> Nokogiri::CSS.xpath_for 'div.divddy input:first, div#where_is input.pancakes_house'
=> ["//div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' divddy ')]//input[position() = 1]", "//div[@id = 'where_is']//input[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' pancakes_house ')]"]
```

Note that the returned array has length two in this case.

Comment: Or more simply: `Nokogiri::CSS.xpath_for "a,b" #=> ["//a", "//b"]`

Comment: @Phrogz: Well yeah but then I wouldn't be able to slip in a Fargo reference ;)

Comment: Great answer, thank you very much! Mandatory reference (OT) http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dJUvPZI3Cr4